# Consolidating data from Subscriber database at Publisher

Tags: sql-server, transactional-replication

We have some tables published from one SQL server and another server subscribed to it.  However we just realised on two tables data was added at the subscriber end that doesn't exist at the publisher.  I can easily enough insert those rows at the published end but I'm struggling to find information that will confirm what will happen when it tries to replicate, so would appreciate some guidance.

Would I need to reinitialise the subscription or handle the conflicts another way?  Or what would be the simplest way to get that data back into the publisher.  This is a one-off - in future all updates will be at the publisher.

Thank you

Comment: @McNets I didn't add a new table - is my question unclear?  Data has been added to an existing table at the subscriber end that I have to bring across to the publisher side.  There is no new table here

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend just [reinitializing the subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/reinitialize-a-subscription?view=sql-server-ver15) **using a new snapshot**. That should synchronize the table at the Subscriber to exactly what the table at the Publisher currently has. There should be no negative ramifications in doing so, rather it's like providing a clean slate for the Subscriber.

If for some reason that doesn't work, you should definitely be able to remove the Article for that table from the Publication, then drop the table at the Subscriber's database, and then re-add the Article for that table to the Publication. But I don't believe you should have to do that, and a basic reinitialization of the subscription should be all that's necessary.

In either case, obviously you'll need to re-apply the same data changes to the Publisher after so that they correctly get synced back down to your Subscriber. Microsoft recommends not directly making data changes to tables in a Subscriber's database if you're not using [updatable subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/updatable-subscriptions-for-transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15).

As a side note, I'd recommend using proper database permissioning in your Subscription database to prevent DML statements from being executed against it accidentally.

Comment: thank you but the issue is there is data at the subscriber side we need to keep - i.e. it needs to come across to the published database.  If reinitialise or recreate the table we lose that data

Comment: @ebooyens Sorry I wrote the above in haste. I meant to say, after you reinitialize the subscription, then re-apply the data change at the Publisher so that they're both correctly in sync. (It's not recommended to make data changes at the Subscriber.) I've updated my answer to add that in.